# Table item many relationship

Tags: mysql, database

I know this is not code realated but wasnt sure where to post it. If this is the wrong spot please let me know where to post as opposed to just a down vote. Basically I am setting up my first DB on my own. I am a little conffused on how to set some tables up. I understand the basic relational model by using a unique ID to pair up tables but what about an item in a table that has many relations.

Examble:

```
User Table 
ID | Name | Email

Product Table 
ID | Name | Price | User_ID
```

Now I know I can pair the 2 using the `User_ID` in the product table but what if the product can belong to multiple users? How do I associate the the product by using the `User_ID` to multiple users?

Comment: you need a third table with columns (product_id, user_id)

Comment: So just a joining table? like `Product_Relation` that has `product_id, user_id`. Then on the `Product Table` loose the `User_ID` column?

Comment: Great! Makes sense now but wasnt sure the standard practice of this stuff. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Just delete the question. As you suggest, it's off topic for this forum